# Spring Inject returning null when called from 'new'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

`I have a @component class where I have a @scheduled method which runs every 5 min. Also I have an @inject class into this class. I am able to call the injected class from the scheduler method.
I have another class, and I am using a constructor to call the @component class using 'new'. The same Injected class is returning null from constructor. see below:

What am i doing wrong?
How is it possible to call the Injected class from the constructor?
Do i need to avoid using 'new' ? Then will the callsomeutility() gets instantiated when the

class loads (basic how constructor works)?

I am getting null pointer exception for the Injected class from the constructor by explicitly

calling 'new'`

```
@component
     public class A{
@Inject
    ServiceClass testservice

 A(){
     callsomeutility();
 }

  public void callsomeutility(){ 
     testservice.methodx(); //return Null
  }

@Scheduled(fixedRate=EVERY_FIVE_MIN)
 public void readeveryfivemin(){
  testservice.methodx();  //works fine
 }
}
public class B{
@Inject
   ServiceClass testservice
A test= new A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` to get the bean for the `A` component. Spring handles the dependency injection, so if you try to create an instance on your own outside the application context, the `ServiceClass` will not be injected.

If you want to run some code after your class has been properly created, you can annotate a method with `@PostConstruct`.

```java
@Component
public class B {
    @Inject;
    A a;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        a.callsomeutility();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Question -  constructors are loaded only once when class is instantiated and not everytime when the class is called within the application. Does the same applies to @PostConstruct? Will this be called only once when class A loads or class B successfully?

Comment: @user7965433 It will only be called once after `B` is fully initialized, in this case.

Comment: @user7965433 constructors are not "loaded". They are called to initialise a newly created instance of a class. Methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` are called *by Spring* when *Spring* creates a new *instance* of a class. This has nothing to do with loading a class.

Comment: @tgdavies So once the spring boot application is built, all classes are compiled and then post construct is called. After that, if any method in the application is executed , the PostConstruct won't be called.

Comment: No, whenever Spring creates an instance of a class which has a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, that method will be called. The instance will usually be created when the application starts, when Spring creates the "application context" and instantiates a single instance of classes annotated with `@Bean`, `@Component` and so on. But Spring can also create beans in other ways, and if it does, the annotated method will be called on those instances too.